# correct syntax to copy from one table row to another (sqlite android)

Tags: android

please, is this the correct syntax for copying a particular row from one table to another?

```
db.execSQL("insert into Route select * from " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE _id = rowId");
```

because for some reason, when i call the method that executes this statement, all the items from the first table are copied into the second table and not the specific row i want. thanks.

this is the method call for copy:

```
public void copyData(long rowId){
db.execSQL("insert into Route select * from " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE _id = rowId"); 
}
```

if not, could you please show me how?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of problems:

First, you're not passing the `rowId` argument to your `copyData()` method in as part of the query, you're using the string literal `rowID`.

Second, `ROWID` [has special meaning](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) in SQLite.  It's a pseudo-column that uniquely identifies each row in a table and is usually the same value that gets assigned to an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column, which I'm guessing is how you have `_id` declared.  The result is that when `WHERE _id = ROWID` is evaluated, the two values always match and therefore all rows are selected.

Comment: hmmm.. yeah, i see what you mean. i had thought of this earlier too but since my method was taking in a parameter. i thought it would be unique to this. so please what should i use as the syntax.. because i have read if am not mistaken, that the row id for a table should always be "_id". does that mean i assign the second table a different primary key Id.  Also, i don't really understand the first point you made. thank you

Comment: sorry for the first point you made, is this what you meant? db.execSQL("insert into Route select * from " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE _id =" + rowId);

Comment: Yes, that would be the way to do it.  The second thing is really just a side effect of the first.